# HTML5 video player, loop only specific frames

Tags: video, html, canvas

I am looking to play and loop only certain parts of a video with the html5 video player. I am hoping for something like `loopstart` and `loopend` attributes for the audio player, but have not found documentation that states that this is available for video.

An example of what I would like to do:

1. when the page loads, the src video plays for the first 5 seconds of the video
2. at that point, the video will loop seconds 6, 7 and 8 of the video...
3. until a link below the player is clicked, at which point seconds 9-12 will play.

Is this something that can be done with the html5 player? I would like to try to do this without resorting to a flash player.

If this is not possible with the html5 video, would a canvas solution be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who cares, I have found a solution. The [JME player](http://www.protofunc.com/jme/) is quite a fancy player with many bells and whistles, including `.currentTime()`.